# Problem with adding value from array to int

Tags: arrays, swift, math, int

Hi I made array in swift

```
var age = [
    "Anna": 25,
    "Billy": 32,
]
```

And I wanted add age of Anna to int

```
var year = age['Anna']+1965
```

but then Im getting error

> Value of optional type 'Int?' must be unwrapped to a value of type
>   'Int'

so I tried to do something like

```
Int(age['Anna'])
```

as you can guess it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of `age['Anna']` is `Optional<Int>`. This is not a `Int`

You have to unwrap:

`var year = (age['Anna'] ?? 0) + 1965`
or

```
guard let age = age['Anna'] else {
return
}
var year age + 1965
```

Comment: There's also `let year = age["Anna", default: 0] + 1965` which uses the default value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Comment: It's really great when you want to mutate the value in the dictionary. `age["Anna"] = (age["Anna"] ?? 0) + 5` can be written as `age["Anna", default: 0] += 5`.

Comment: @vacawama yes. This is really useful. I tried to find such syntax previously but with no result. Stackoverflow is really great.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to unwrap the Optional ?

```
if let ageAnna = age["Anna"] {
    let year = ageAnna + 1965
    print(year)
}
```